# Keep GET connection open in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript), you can keep a connection open with the server to listen for any changes. Is there any possible way to do it with jQuery's `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` methods?

Comment: You should have a look at [web sockets](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html) instead for that type of requirement

Comment: There's nothing (that I could see, it's quite long) in that question that suggests you can keep a connection open.  $.get is shorthand for $.ajax.  Consider `$.ajax` as being like a sending a letter - you get back a distinct "package" or set of results - it's not like a pipe where more results can keep coming while you process them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the simplest level, put your AJAX call into a function, then create an interval:

```html
setInterval(ajaxCall, 300000); //300000 MS == 5 minutes

function ajaxCall() {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch_details.php',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(response){
         // Perform operation on the return value
         alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it the same thing with `$.post()`? Just wondering...

Comment: Not really, But while $.ajax() is customizable, You can as well have it like this.

$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
}); 

Do you understand?

Comment: I know that the attributes are different. I'm just asking "Does it work if I replace it?"

Comment: `$.get` and `$.post` are both shorthand for `$.ajax` with the `type:` set and slightly different parameters.  "does it work if I replace it" - if you replace `$.ajax({type:'get'` with a `$.post` will depend on whether your server accepts get/post for that action, so not really a yes/no.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that I was asking about GET.

Comment: It's alright... you can do the same for $.get(). Kindly rate the answer for others to benefit from it.